# CSS Parent Element

Tags: javascript, css

I want to dynamically apply CSS style based on parent css property of a div element. Is there a way in javascript to do this/ is this possible? Example of code :

```
<div clas="parent">
     <div class="child">
          <div class="x"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Based on parent class css property, i want to toggle css  property for class x

Comment: `if($('.parent').hasClass('someClass')){$('.parent').find('.x').addClass('anotherclass');}`

Comment: That's not a CSS property.

Comment: Must have misread it, sorry.  I'd recommend saving the property to a css class and adding the class though, not the property directly.

Comment: I  am using angularjs, css property is defined in class  names. 
    Example :   .parent { color:green;}, ,child{ background:black;}

Comment: why can't you do that is pure CSS? Why does JavaScript need to be involved?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to use JavaScript to toggle something based on a parent class. You can just do it in pure CSS.

```
.parent .child .x {
     background-color: red; /* default */
}


.parent.someClass .child .x {
     background-color: yellow; /* overrides the default with specificity */
}
```

Comment: This answers the `X` in this [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  This is the right way.

Comment: @cale_b He specifically included the word dynamic when asking the question.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon And the CSS rule will be applied dynamically when the parent class is added/removed. ;) It all depends on what the OP really needs. If they really need JS, than they can use a JS solution.

Comment: I want to dynamically set the property, as in  different scenarios i want different value

Comment: @FrontDev so use different classes with different values. The question is quite broad to begin with.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, 
    Scenario is :   depending on the  background property of parent element, i want to change the value of color for  the div with class "X".
   example if parent has grey color, then class x should be green. and if parent has black color then class x should be red.

Comment: And have sun with the fact that color code will either be in hex or rbg depending on the browser. You really can not add classes and not have to deal with this? That would simplfy the whole thing and make your application run faster than having to loop over all the elements, read styles, and add/remove properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
var y = document.getElementById('child').parentNode.className;
if (y=="active") {
document.getElementById('x').style.background = '#ff0000';
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/simsketch/pen/vgNjdp

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was trying to use getElementByClassName and  console was throwing me an error, not sure why. I saw it in console and the element was present.

Answer (score 0):

First, you grab element using `querySelector`, then you can change class using `className`.

In your example, to change color to red  you could do:

```
document.querySelector('.parent .child div').className = "x"
```

To toggle class you could use `classList.toggle("x")`

```
document.querySelector('.parent .child div').classList.toggle("x")`
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to `jQuery`, you can acheive it with very specific selectors like so:

```js
$('.x').each(function() {
  if ($(this).closest($('.parent')).hasClass('makeBlue')) {
    $(this).addClass('turnBlue');
  }
  if ($(this).closest($('.parent')).hasClass('makeRed')) {
    $(this).addClass('turnRed');
  }
});
```

```css
.x.turnBlue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
.x.turnRed {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent makeBlue">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="x"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent makeRed">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="x"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```